# Application of Poincare recurrence to Baker's map?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Please see figures at https://www.pks.mpg.de/de/nonlinear-dynamics-and-time-series-analysis/visualization-of-dynamical-systems/poincare-recurrences.

I heard that one of the applications of the Poincare recurrence theorem (which I do not state here, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem) is to explain that the original image reappear in the Baker's map, but I do not understand how this follows.

The Baker's map is a certain map defined on the square, and Poincare recurrence theorem applied to this map just gives us that each individual point returns, under high iterates of the map, arbitrarily close to its original location, but this does not explain that the image as a whole "returns" to itself.

Comment: I'm guessing that this map  is the also called Arnold's Cat Map. Link:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map

Comment: Thanks for the link! The pictures are really amazing

Comment: The Poincare recurrence theorem has nothing to do with periodicity of the the Arnold's Cat Map

Comment: Moreover the baker map is something very different ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_map ) which is non-periodic